# How do I use SSL Certy purchased from Go daddy on my Heroku app running a node js framework? Note : I don't have Heroku paid dynos

Tags: ssl, heroku

How do I use SSL Certificate purchased from Go daddy on my Heroku app running a node js framework? Note : I don't have Heroku paid dynos.
I purchased a standard SSL Certificate and have downloaded its content. How should I configure them to my app now? My domain is working smooth, which I bought from Go daddy as well.
Please help me out.

Comment: [both ACM and custom SSL are only possible on paid dynos with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl). 

So there is no good way to make this work.

Comment: I thought so! Thank you.